# Thymeleaf conditions with iterator

Tags: thymeleaf

I have come across this ability of thymeleaf which based on the iterator I can specify the class of the dom element.

```
<tr th:each="item,iter : ${items}" th:class="${iter.odd} ? 'info' : '' " >
```

However, I want to do that on a specific row (let's say the 5th) and none of these statements work

```
 <tr th:each="item,iter : ${items}" th:class="${iter == 5} ? 'info' : '' " >
 <tr th:each="item,iter : ${items}" th:class="${iter} == 5 ? 'info' : '' " >
```

Is this not the appropriate syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iter` variable is called the [status variable](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) and it isn't an integer (which is why you can't compare it to 5, like you're trying to do).  Rather it's an object with properties you can use.

In this case, you should use the `count` property, like this:

```html
 <tr th:each="item,iter : ${items}" th:class="${iter.count == 5} ? 'info' : ''" >
```